# i want to add accordion inside the cms block, but it is not taking

Tags: cms-block, magento2.4.3, accordion

i want to add accordion inside the cms block, but it is not taking

this is the code i want to add

```
<div id="accordion" data-mage-init='{
"accordion":{
"activate": 2,
"collapsible": true,
"openedState": "",
"multipleCollapsible": true
}}'>
<h3>Information </h3>
<div class="disp" data-role="collapsible">
<div data-role="trigger">
<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="content"><ul>
<li><a href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Terms and Condition</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Start a Return</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

after save it will become

```
<div id="accordion" data-mage-init="{
">
<h3>Information</h3>
<div class="disp" data-role="collapsible">
<div data-role="trigger">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Terms and Condition</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Start a Return</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add phtml file in CMS block and add code in phtml file.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::information.phtml"}}
```

add phtml on below path

```
app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/Magneto_Theme/templates/information.phtml
```

Note: CMS Block not support some additional tag and script so never add code directly in CMS Block.